# How to write User Defined exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

hi can any one tell me how to write user defined exceptions in C#?As we have in Java can we write in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is practically the same as it is in Java - you extend the `Exception` class.

In the most basic form.

```
public class CustomException : System.Exception
{
  public CustomException()
  {
  }

  public CustomException(string message)
    : base(message)
  {
  }

  public CustomException(string message, System.Exception innerException)
    : base(message, innerException)
  {
  }
}
```

To this, then add the data that you want to capture using either fields or properties.

Out of interest, before answering this question, I checked the Microsoft Design Guildlines on Custom Exceptions. [Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (MSDN)

1. Avoid deep namespace hierarchies.
2. If possible, derive from one the provided common base exceptions, i.e., `ArgumentException`. **HOWEVER** Do not derive from `ApplicationException`. It is not harmful, it is no point in doing so. [MSDN Blog Post on ApplicationException](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2006/06/23/644822.aspx).
3. Use the "Exception" suffix.
4. Make exceptions serializable by implementing the `ISerializable` interface. Apparently an exception must be serializable to work correctly across application domain and remoting boundaries.
5. Store security-sensitive information in a private exception state, add a SecurityPermission attribute to ensure that only trusted code can get the information.

I *highly* recommend reading the [Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 16):

You want to inherit from `System.Exception` and preferrably provide (at minimum) the same public constructors and pass the parameters on to the base constructors. Add the relevant properties and/or methods you deem appropriate for your particular need.

```
public class MyException : System.Exception
{
     public MyException() : base() { }
     public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
     public MyException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
}
```

Comment: According to the .NET Framework Design Guidelines, you are supposed to inherit directly from Exception unless you have a really good reason to pick something else.

Comment: @Jonathan: All systems back to normal. Deleted my stupid answer and removed my useless comment. Upvoted the answer in the name of SO spirit. Thanks for correction.