# What is this colon in a constructor definition called?

Tags: c#, terminology

When defining a constructor in C#, you can use a colon (as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852893/977472)):

```
 public class Custom : OtherClass {
      public Custom(string s) : base(s) { }
 }
```

**What is this colon called?**  <sup><sub>(It's awfully hard to read about it without knowing what it's called.)</sub></sup>

Note that I'm asking about the colon in the **constructor** definition, not the one showing inheritance in the class definition.

Comment: It's not a method - it's a constructor, and it's chaining to another constructor. (This part of the syntax is called a *constructor-initializer*.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks, I've fixed the terminology in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet, your comment actually answers the question.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't in enough detail for me to be happy to post it as an answer, and I didn't have enough time to put in that detail...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't a method definition, it's a constructor definition; the colon is used to specify the superclass constructor call which must be called prior to the subclass's constructor.

In Java, the `super` keyword is used but it must be the first operation in a subclass constructor, whereas C# uses a syntax closer to C++'s initializer lists.

If a subclass' superclass' constructor does not have any parameters then an explicit call to the parent constructor is not necessary, it is only when arguments are required or if you want to call a specific overloaded constructor must you use this syntax.

Java:

```
public class Derived extends Parent {
    public Derived(String x) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

C#:

```
public class Derived : Parent {
    public Derived(String x) : base(x) {
    }
}
```

#### Update

The C# Language Specification 5.0 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 has an explanation in section 10.11.1 "Constructor initializers"

> All instance constructors (except those for class `Object`) implicitly include an invocation of another instance constructor immediately before the *constructor-body*. The constructor to implicitly invoke is determined by the *constructor-initializer*:

So the offiical technical term for this syntax...

```
: base(x, y, z)
```

...is "constructor-initializer", however the specification does not specifically call out the colon syntax and give it its own name. This author assumes the specification does not concern itself with such trivialities.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `c#` does not call it a `superclass`, base rather a `base` class

Comment: @Dai, I'm asking what that colon is *called*, not what it *does*.