# Understanding syntactic variations of a constructor definition block

Tags: c++, class, syntax, constructor, definitions

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29423148/2623899), I think, but for C++, not C# (though the same answer may apply to both).

My question is also similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/2623899) (of which it has been marked a duplicate).  The ***difference***, however, is that that question asks about the ***constructor prototype***, whereas mine asks about the ***constructor definition block***.

Consider the following constructor definition block:

```
template <class T>
SimpleMatrix<T>::SimpleMatrix(int rows, int cols, const T& initVal)
  : m_data(rows * cols, initVal)
  , m_rows(rows)
  , m_cols(cols)
{}
```

I'm a C++ newbie, and the `CallOne() : call_two(), call_three(), call_four() {}` syntax is confusing me.

Is it equivalent to the following code block?

```
template <class T>
SimpleMatrix<T>::SimpleMatrix(int rows, int cols, const T& initVal)
{
vector <T> m_data(rows * cols, initVal);
m_rows = rows;
m_cols = cols;
}
```

Note that inside the `SimpleMatrix` class definition, `m_data`, `m_rows`, and `m_cols` are declared in the `private` block as follows:

```
private:
  int m_rows;
  int m_cols;

  vector<T> m_data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NOTE:** Whether this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) would be grounds for some debate. In technical terms, yes, it is, and I agree with marking it as such. For a complete newbie, however, it may be hard to derive the answer from the duplicate. This answer, plus the duplicate question, create the whole picture.

In loose terms, yet, it is the same.

The first is an **initialization list**, which initializes each of the variables. The second is **assigning** values.

To understand why the first is generally superior, we have to understand the second. When we assign to a variable in the constructor, the code must first initialize it with some default value, and then assign the value we wanted to that newly initialized variable. Thus, it takes two steps.

When we use an initialization list, we are initializing the variable with a value of *our* choosing, instead of a value chosen automatically. Thus, it only takes one step.

It may seem like a pedantic little detail, but every little bit helps when optimizing.

This is the same concept whether it appears in the constructor's header or implementation.

Comment: I can link you, yes, but you will want to get used to finding documentation yourself. :) [Use a web search for "c++ initialization list".](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+initialization+list)

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. The top four on that web search are excellent, or you can jump right to (my personal favorite)[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/].

Comment: with regard to your last sentence, does this mean i don't even need to do this in a definition block -- or maybe don't even need a definition block?  can i have everything in one line in the prototype?

Comment: Not a problem. I actually recommend [duckduckgo.com](https://www.duckduckgo.com) over Google, especially for programming searches. More relevant and accurate results, especially from StackOverflow and documentation.

Comment: @dbliss, I just noticed your edited comment. No, you no longer need a definition block. Sometimes I'll define my constructor with its initialization list in my header, and just leave a `{}` (no semicolon) at the end, because the constructor needed nothing else.

Comment: aha, OK, that clarifies for me why this is a duplicate of the other question.  thanks!